# usepager false not working on runtime flexigrid

Tags: php, flexigrid

I am using flexigrid with PHP what i want is hide pager when there is only 1 page and show pager if pages are more then 1. I think this can be sort out if i can hide or show pager at run-time I tried below code but its not working

i.e `$("#div").flexReload({usepager:true});`

Comment: I got solution for this :-) just added some code in flexigrid.js file

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#div')
    .flexOptions({ usepager:true })
    .flexReload();
```